# FindControl suddenly returning object reference error (ASP.NET/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol

I have the following code in my Global.asax file:

```
System.Web.UI.Page webPage = (System.Web.UI.Page)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler;
string date = ((Literal)webPage.FindControl("ltlGenTime")).Text;
```

The control *definitely* exists on the webpage, and I've verified this by checking the webPage object and its base class, and it's *definitely* a literal control.

Now I have made a change which seems to have caused this - I created a master page for all my pages. But I'm confused as the webPage object still has the control I require listed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Master pages modify the page control hierarchy, so first you need find the content placeholde from master and then locate the actual control - for example,

```
Master.FindControl("YourContentPlaceholderId").FindControl("ControlName");
```

See [this article](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/5127.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `ltlGenTime` control? I'm guessing it's on the master.

If it is on the master page then you will need to use

```
string date = ((Literal)webPage.Master.FindControl("ltlGenTime")).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `FindControl` does not do recursive search. You might have to locate the appropriate container under which it resides.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this **recursive FindControl** function I found [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/recursive-pagefindcontrol.html).

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id) 
{ 
    if (root.ID == id)
    { 
        return root; 
    } 

    foreach (Control c in root.Controls) 
    { 
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id); 
        if (t != null) 
        { 
            return t; 
        } 
    } 

    return null; 
}
```